# A conjecture from Jean Varouchas on Kahler varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

**Conjecture:** Let $\pi: X\to X'$ be a proper flat surjective morphism of complex spaces.
If $X$ is Kahler, is $X'$ Kahler?

This conjecture when $X$ and $X'$ are smooth solved by Jean Varouchas from Nancy and by some assumption of geometric flatness of $\pi$ solved also by him on singular setting.

But Is there any reference to give a solution to this conjecture?

see https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/torus_images.pdf

Varouchas, J.: [Stabilite de la classe des varietes kahleriennes par certains morphismes propres](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01389138#page-1). Invent. Math.77(1984), no. 1, 117–127.

Varouchas, J.: [Kahler spaces and proper open morphisms](https://eudml.org/doc/164492). Math. Ann.283(1989),13–52.

Comment: In general, from Lemma 4.6 of Fujiki result  say that $X'$ belongs to the Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ if $X$ be Kahler . A. Fujiki, Closedness of the Douady spaces of compact Kahler spaces, Publ. Res. Inst. Math. Sci.
14 (1978/79), 1–52

Comment: In fact, my previous comment holds when fibers may do not have same dimensions, and when fibers $X_s$ have same dimension, of course Varouchas result is stronger

Comment: More comments: If fibers  and base of the proper flat surjective morphism of complex spaces  $\pi:X\to X'$ are Kahler, then $X$ is not Kahler manifold in general. So I don't know under which condition $X$ can Kahler manifold ?

Comment: Note that if $X$ be Moishezon, then $X'$ is Moishezon(this is due to Artin.), but I don't know if $X'$  be Moishezon, then $X$ is Moishezon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem was solved by Barlet and Varouchas in 
[this paper.](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=BSMF_1989__117_3_327_0)

The base $X'$ is assumed to be reduced (surely this is OK for you), and the fibers pure dimensional (also certainly acceptable).